# Tizen #SDB giving error "No such file or directory" while installing wgt file

Tags: tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

I'am trying to install `HelloAccessoryProvider.wgt` file on my Gear s3 watch but sdb is giving me following error.

> `error: failed to get status of 'HelloAccessoryProvider.wgt': No such file or directory`.

My watch is connected to #tizen studio and USB debugging option is also enabled.
I have already created the certificate using Samsung certificate extension. 
How can i remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research about the scenarios which can cause such error type, but the only reason I could find was invalid path to a wgt file. I was not able to get this error type in any other situations, including problems with certificate.

Please ensure that you are using the full path to a file (or you are starting sdb command in the directory which contains the file). Also notice that this path need to be your local machine, not remote device path. 
I used below shell command to install wgt file:

*sdb install /path/to/TizenStudio/project/Basic.wgt*

it pushes the file /path/to/TizenStudio/project/Basic.wgt to your Tizen device and then installs the application.

The another problem, which I can imagine basing on my experience with Tizen Studio is that the path *seem* to be valid, but Tizen Studio for some reason *didn't* create the wgt file properly. You can re-create the file using right-click on project and selecting 'Build Signed Package'. The wgt file should be generated in the main directory of the project.